# Launch Chrome with notifications allowed

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

are there any flags available for launching Chrome with Notifications allowed either globally or for a specific domain?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en

Comment: I need to launch a Chrome instance where Notifications are globally allowed, or allowed for a specific domain. Same with Firefox.